# Nested for loop with 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I replace the numbers in the array which can be multiplied by 2 the string "even" and also for "odd".

```js
var numbers = [
  [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
  [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
  [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
  [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
  [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
  [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
  [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
  [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
  [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
  [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
    if(numbers[i][j] % 2 === 0) {
      numbers[i][j] += " even";
    } else {
      numbers [i][j] += " odd";
    }
   
    console.log(numbers[j][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. The problem is the `console.log(numbers[j][i]);`. It should be `console.log(numbers[i][j]);`. (switch i and j).
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the indices, for displaying the actual element. If not, you get some elements without changed values.

```
console.log(numbers[i][j]);
//                  ^  ^
```

```js
var numbers = [
  [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
  [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
  [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
  [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
  [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
  [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
  [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
  [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
  [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
  [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
    if (numbers[i][j] % 2 === 0) {
      numbers[i][j] += " even";
    } else {
      numbers[i][j] += " odd";
    }
    console.log(numbers[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had to remove the + from += so the result is only even, odd, even odd...without the numbers

Answer (score 2):

If you mean replace the number by string , you can do this but the arrays must defined to be any :

```
 const numbers: any = [
  [243, 12, 23, 12, 45, 45, 78, 66, 223, 3],
  [34, 2, 1, 553, 23, 4, 66, 23, 4, 55],
  [67, 56, 45, 553, 44, 55, 5, 428, 452, 3],
  [12, 31, 55, 445, 79, 44, 674, 224, 4, 21],
  [4, 2, 3, 52, 13, 51, 44, 1, 67, 5],
  [5, 65, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 43, 23, 4424],
  [74, 532, 6, 7, 35, 17, 89, 43, 43, 66],
  [53, 6, 89, 10, 23, 52, 111, 44, 109, 80],
  [67, 6, 53, 537, 2, 168, 16, 2, 1, 8],
  [76, 7, 9, 6, 3, 73, 77, 100, 56, 100]
];

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
    if ( numbers[i][j] % 2 === 0) {
      numbers [i][j] = 'even';
    } else {
      numbers [i][j] = 'odd';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is looking now like this:
243 odd
12 even
 23 odd
12 even
45 odd
78 even
66 even
But I would like to look like this :
odd
even
odd....etc

Comment: I update the code and it works for me , please try it and give me a feedback

Comment: Yes it is working for me as well. I had to remove the + from += "even".